# How to check if external monitor is turned on and connected

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, suspend, monitor

I'm looking for a scripted way to check if the external monitor is on and connected.

My Ubuntu laptop often fails to turn on the external monitor after sleep or a blank screen. I've long since [solved the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333688/how-to-get-external-monitor-to-reconnect-after-sleep-or-power-off) using `xset dpms force on; xset dpms force off;`.

This solution is less than perfect because the monitor goes through a cycle of black screen / blue screen, and the `xset` operation must be executed while the monitor is in the black screen state. I often repeat the command multiple times until it works.

If I could check if the monitor is properly connected I could better automate the script that re-engages the monitor using `xset dpms force on|off`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter (`grep`, `awk`, `sed`, etc.) the output of several commands that provide info on screens/monitors.
If you only need to know if the external monitor is connected, more than one of them are possibly enough.
I am listing below a few examples of what I see. I don't have an external monitor to test, but I guess you can work out the details.

1. `xrandr`.

   ```
   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1344 x 744, maximum 8192 x 8192
   LVDS connected primary 1344x744+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
      1344x744_60.00  59.90*+
      ...
   HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   ```
2. `xdpyinfo`

   ```
   ...
   default screen number:    0
   number of screens:    1

   screen #0:
     ... (a lot of useful information)
   ```
3. `inxi -aG`

   As per [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/inxi.1.html), it can give info on the real monitor/s (e.g., "the real  monitor size, not the Xorg full Screen diagonal size, which can be quite different"), although I am not seeing that.
4. `hwinfo | grep -i -B 3 -A 3 monitor`

   ```
    ...
    37: None 00.0: 10002 LCD Monitor
      [Created at monitor.125]
      Unique ID: rdCR.0BRfQK9ozR8
      Parent ID: vSkL.mJc3+3Ia6n4
      Hardware Class: monitor
      Model: "AUO LCD Monitor"
      Vendor: AUO "AUO"
      Device: eisa 0x20ec
      Resolution: 1366x768@60Hz
    ...
   ```

Comment: hwinfo | awk '/Monitor/,/^$/'

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Gnome extension Argos to check if my second DELL monitor is connected. And span the wallpaper if it is. Zoom the wallpaper if it isn't. (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1176/argos/)

The script checks every 15 seconds. (This is done by naming the file ?.1r.15s+.sh)

My Argos script file is:
wallpaper.1r.15s+.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

connected=$(xrandr | awk '/ connected/ {count++} END {print count}')
wallpaper=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options)

if [ "$connected" -gt 1 ] && [ "$wallpaper" == "'zoom'" ]; then
span=$(gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options spanned)
fi

if [ "$connected" -lt 2 ] && [ "$wallpaper" == "'spanned'" ]; then
span=$(gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options zoom)
fi
echo " | iconName=folder-pictures-symbolic refresh=true trim=false"
echo "---"
echo "# screens: $connected"
echo "Wallpaper: $wallpaper"
```