# Display settings are not persistent after sleep

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, suspend

My setup: the build-in display of the laptop and an external one (HannStar Display Corp 32'') connected via HDMI.

After I am away for a while and the monitors are going to sleep, often (not always)  the following happens: only the build-in monitor awakes, if then I again join the displays, then distribution of the apps is changed, so they are moved to the build-in display and the virtual screens (ctrl+alt+left/right arrows) are squashed into one.

This is very similar to this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131558/second-external-monitor-not-waking-up) but I can easily turn back the external display. The problem is that the distribution of apps is changed.

Ubuntu 21.10

Dell Precision 3561 (build-in display: 15,6" IPS (3840 x 2160))

Graphic: NVIDIA T600, 4GB using *nvidia-driver-510*

Comment: Hi. May not be what you want but it should work that way. When the external monitor is not there the apps will move to the internal one. A normal behavior.